# Which version of spring supports open jdk or vice versa please confirm

Tags: spring, java

current version of spring we are using is 3.2 .Is it compatible with open jdk 7

we are getting the following error after replacing the jre and jdk to open jdk

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'applicationContext-main' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1041)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:273)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1008)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(Singlet
```

This is the full stack trace

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3f9a23f5: startup date [Mon Dec 12 05:35:37 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ec73967: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
Application context could not be created. Will now exit
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to return specified BeanFactory instance: factory key [applicationContext-main], from group with resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'applicationContext-main' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:409)
```

Below this is the stack trace which is shared earlier

Comment: Post the full stack trace instead of a snippet. Unless you are using internal sun classes there should be nothing preventing you from using OpenJDK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply denim can you check the latest stack trace and help us??

Comment: Apparently it doesn't find your resources where it expects them to be. So either it worked before by shear luck or there is an issue with resolving paths with OpenJDK. You are only switching to OpenJDK you aren't upgrading from 6 to 7?

Comment: we are switching from oracle jdk to open jdk

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question are you also upgrading the version... The initial change from Oracle to OpenJDK was already clear from your question.

Comment: initial oracle version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root current version of openjdk  java -version
java version "1.7.0_05-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.2.1) (linux-gnu build 1.7.0_05-icedtea-b21)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)   \n can this be a problem ?

Comment: You are at least downgrading to an older patch version. You might want to use the latest 1.7 OpenJDK build.

Comment: Or, you know, upgrade to Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Spring 3.2 [supports OpenJDK 7](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.17.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-3.2-java7).

It's also worth noting that [OpenJDK 7 is the reference implementation of Java 7](https://jdk7.java.net/java-se-7-ri/). If a project doesn't work with OpenJDK 7, it's really not Java 7 compatible!

Please also note that OpenJDK 7 <del>u111</del> u121 is the latest security update. u79, that you are using, contains **known security vulnerabilities**.

Comment: Can any one give with actual link from where i can download official open jdk 7 tar files latest  . I cannot use Yum or app .get commands due to network restrictions. Your help is much appeciated

Comment: Grab the latest OpenJDK 7 update from here: https://java.net/projects/openjdk7/downloads?field=date&order=desc

Comment: I also fixed up https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/jdk7u/Main to point to the source releases

Comment: This link points to the source files and does not contain jre. How can get the binaries of both jdk and jre for open jdk 7 latest updated.

Comment: OpenJDK does not publish binary releases :( Some third parties distribute builds, like Azul (http://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/), but these are no official OpenJDK builds.